# obtain recursion level in C language?

Tags: c, unix, recursion

I was writing a recursive function (in C language) and needed a way to know if the recursion had finished. I wonder if I can do it withought variables or flags. With a function for example.

For instance, if the recursion went 3 levels down and then came back up, is there a way to check if I am at level 1....withought using flags?

lev 1 -> lev 2 -> lev 3 -> lev 2 -> lev 1 (check here)

Comment: good to see the Rush bass player branching out into programming! ;)

Comment: Neil Peart's the drummer from Rush (Geddy Lee is the base player)!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add an extra argument to your function, along the lines of `int level`. Then pass `level+1` when calling yourself recursively, and pass `0` (or `1` if you prefer) to the initial call.

Comment: He specified "I wonder if I can do it withought variables or flags", so in this case, it's not really suitable, even though I don't know why this is not a solution for him.

Comment: Well, I know that is possible and it is a suitable solution. But as Vincent B. mentioned, I was wondering if there was another way of doing that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The solution Vincent B mentioned is not C, and even with variants/extensions of C (like "GNU C") that might give you the tools to try to attempt it, it could still fail horribly if the compiler is smart enough to optimize out your recursion and replace it with loops.

Comment: Ok I will stick to the normal solution. 

...I didn't know that compiler could optimize your code in a way that replaces recursion with loops.

Comment: The compiler can do any optimization it likes as long as the observable behavior by a correct program (one which does not invoke UB) matches the behavior specified.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to play with stack ...

```
int  func(void *p,int n, int stacksize)
{
 char marker;
 int depth =  (int)p -(int)&marker ;
 printf("%d --- %d --- %d\r\n", n,depth, stacksize?depth/stacksize:0);
 if (n>10)
    return depth ;

 return func(p,n+1,stacksize);
}


int main()
{
  char marker;
  int onepass = func(&marker,11,0);

  func(&marker,0,onepass );
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about portability, you can unwind the call-stack manually. But I suspect R's solution is *vastly* better for your problem.

Comment: Note that if the compiler is any good and the algorithm isn't horribly complex, there might be no call stack...

Comment: Something more sophisticated than tail-call optimization? I haven't seen many naive programmers trip and fall into tail-call-optimizable recursive functions, but you never know.

Comment: Give it a few more years and compilers will optimize most recursive functions with constant space (aside from return addresses) down to loops. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the actual problem. Without storing some sort of flag, you can't tell (in a portable way, that is).

However, it's possible that your recursive function happens to alter some data in such a way that it can tell whether it has previously already entered into a certain recursion depth. On the other hand, this is just a complicated way of saying that you're storing a flag value.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will settle with flags then.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just check the call stack, but it will depend on the real level or recursion you are dealing with, else if it's for debug/understanding purpose only, go with R.. solution.

Comment: wich function allows to check the call stack?